# Study if the $\forall x \exists y R(x,y)\land \forall y \neg R(c,y)$ is logically valid, a contingency or a contradiction.

Tags: logic, proof-verification, first-order-logic

> Study if the $\forall x \exists y R(x,y)\land \forall y \neg R(c,y)$ is logically valid, a contingency or a contradiction.

Take $A = \{ a, c \}$. Since for $\forall x \exists y R(x,y)$ we can set our $y$ to be some constant $a$ and $x$ to be $c$, which leads us to $R(c,a)$. But since $\forall y \neg R(c,y)$, we can take our $y$ to be $a$ again, that is, we get $\neg R(c,a)$. So any model on $A$ ends up with $R(c,a) \land \neg R(c,a)$, and therefore, the formula is a contradiction.

Is the argument above true? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x=c$. Then $$\exists yR(c, y)\wedge \forall y\neg R(c, y).$$ But $\forall y\neg R(c, y)$ equivalent to $\neg\exists y R(c, y)$ so the formula is $$\exists yR(c, y)\wedge \neg\exists y R(c, y),$$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot argue that the formula is a contradiction by considering only models with the particular universe $\{a,c\}$. For that you need to **either** argue that *every model*, no matter what the universe is, will fail to satisfy the sentence, **or** actually infer an explicit contradiction from the formula.

The latter seems to be easiest. You have $\forall x\exists y\,R(x,y)$ and $\forall y\,\neg R(c,y)$ separately. Instantiate $x$ to $c$ to get $\exists y\,R(c,y)$ -- but that is (equivalent to) the negation of $\forall y\,\neg R(c,y)$, so with a minimum of additional footwork (the details of which depend on your precise proof system) you have an explicit contradiction right there.

Comment: Hum... I see. I am wondering though, that the model I found would work for any case, right? Since $a$ is arbitrary. The method I used was really the tableaux method for this case. I tried to redo the steps here, but the original proof was a tableau with every branch closed. Could I infer from that that the formula is actually a contradiction?

Comment: @user313212: If you phrase it explicitly as a tableaux proof, then it would work. But if you want to word it without mentioning the tableaux mechanics, then it's a shorthand for a more verbose argument that works for _all_ structures, not just ones where the universe has those two elements.

Comment: All right! Thank you for clarifying it! :)